# Jquery with dynamic created html row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I created dynamic rows (with java script code) in html table. Now I want to autofil my all input fields with jquery. But its not working. Here is my code :

```js
// onkeyup event will occur when the user
// release the key and calls the function
// assigned to this event
function GetDetail(str) {
  if (str.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById("bbb").value = "";
    document.getElementById("ccc").value = "";
    return;
  } else {

    // Creates a new XMLHttpRequest object
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

      // Defines a function to be called when
      // the readyState property changes
      if (this.readyState == 4 &&
        this.status == 200) {

        // Typical action to be performed
        // when the document is ready
        var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

        // Returns the response data as a
        // string and store this array in
        // a variable assign the value
        // received to first name input field

        document.getElementById("bbb").value = myObj[0];

        document.getElementById("ccc").value = myObj[1];
      }
    };

    // xhttp.open("GET", "filename", true);
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "gfg.php?user_id=" + str, true);

    // Sends the request to the server
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
}
```

```html
<td><input type="text" class="form-control text-end" name="scode[]" id="aaa" onkeyup="GetDetail(this.value)" value=""></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control text-end" name="servproname[]" id="bbb"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control text-end" name="qty[]" id="ccc" onchange="Calc(this);"></td>
```

Comment: You're not using jQuery anywhere, just vanilla JS.

Comment: yes but this code work fine with normal row. I want it to work with dynamic created html row

Comment: You shouldn't use the same ID in every row. `getElementById()` won't look in the current row, it will look for the first use of that ID on the page.  Use classes, not IDs. And you need to pass the current row to `GetDetail()` so it can search for the classes in the current row of the table.

Comment: What does that have to do with jQuery?

Comment: can you give me little example of code with classes and differnt id, actually i am new to coding

Comment: @barmar sir how can we format sub total and total generated by group by with roll up in mysql php????

Comment: Check for the grouped columns being `NULL` when producing the HTML. Those are the subtotals and grand totals.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the current row as a parameter to GetDetail(), so it can find the input fields in that row.

You should use classes rather than IDs, since IDs must be unique.

```js
// onkeyup event will occur when the user
// release the key and calls the function
// assigned to this event
function GetDetail(row) {
  let str = row.querySelector(".scode").value;
  if (str.length == 0) {
    row.querySelector(".servproname").value = "";
    row.querySelector(".qty").value = "";
    return;
  } else {
    // Creates a new XMLHttpRequest object
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

      // Defines a function to be called when
      // the readyState property changes
      if (this.readyState == 4 &&
        this.status == 200) {

        // Typical action to be performed
        // when the document is ready
        var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

        // Returns the response data as a
        // string and store this array in
        // a variable assign the value
        // received to first name input field

        row.querySelector(".servproname").value = myObj[0];

        row.querySelector(".qty").value = myObj[1];
      }
    };

    // xhttp.open("GET", "filename", true);
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "gfg.php?user_id=" + str, true);

    // Sends the request to the server
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="scode form-control text-end" name="scode[]" onkeyup="GetDetail(this.closest('tr'))" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="servproname form-control text-end" name="servproname[]" id="bbb"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="qty form-control text-end" name="qty[]" id="ccc" onchange="Calc(this);"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ths code still not working

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: not a tall sir, its absolutely fine and working.  Error was in php file which i corrected . Thanks for your extremely positive guidance

Comment: Sir can you guide me about one more problem ? I created  form in php and html with mysql. Now i want that after submitting value remain in the form and I also want Edit and print option on the same form. How can i do it in php mysql. If you have time than please guide me

Comment: You can use AJAX instead of normal form submission. Or when you submit the form, the server can respond with the form page with all the values filled in from what you submitted.

Comment: BARMAR sir how can we handle autocomplete search with dynamic created rows. can u suggest

Comment: That's too complicated to explain in a comment. Google "javascript autocomplete" and you should be able to find examples.

Comment: What changes need to be done in script if I want to use depdent drop down list with classes